# Return list of points (x,y,z) from C to C# using PInvoke

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I need to return a list of points i have from a C dll to a C# application using PInvoke. These are points in 3 dimensions [x,y,z]. The number of points varies by what kind of model it is. In C i handle this a linked list of structs. But I don't see how i can pass this on to C#.

The way I see it, I have to return a flexible two dimensional array, probably in a struct.

Any suggestions to how this can be done? Both ideas on how to return it in C and how to access it in C# are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linked list of structs *could* be passed back, but it would be quite a hassle to deal with, as you would have to write code to loop through the pointers, reading and copying the data from native memory into managed memory space.  I would recommend a simple array of structs instead.

If you have a C struct like the following (assuming 32-bit ints)...

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}
```

... then you'd represent it nearly the same way in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential]
struct Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
}
```

Now to pass an array back, it would be easiest to have your native code allocate the array and pass it back as a pointer, along with another pointer specifying the size in elements.

Your C prototype might look like this:

```
// Return value would represent an error code
// (in case something goes wrong or the caller
// passes some invalid pointer, e.g. a NULL).
// Caller must pass in a valid pointer-to-pointer to
// capture the array and a pointer to capture the size
// in elements.
int GetPoints(Point ** array, int * arraySizeInElements);
```

The P/Invoke declaration would then be this:

```
[DllImport("YourLib.dll")]
static extern int GetPoints(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] out Point[] array,
    out int arraySizeInElements);
```

The `MarshalAs` attribute specifies that the array should be marshaled using the size specified in the second parameter (you can read more about this at MSDN, ["Default Marshaling for Arrays"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).

If you use this approach, note that you *must* use [`CoTaskMemAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to allocate the native buffer as this is what the .NET marshaler expects.  Otherwise, you will get memory leaks and/or other errors in your application.

Here is a snippet from the simple example I compiled while verifying my answer:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

extern "C"
int GetPoints(Point ** array, int * arraySizeInElements)
{
    // Always return 3 items for this simple example.
    *arraySizeInElements = 3;

    // MUST use CoTaskMemAlloc to allocate (from ole32.dll)
    int bytesToAlloc = sizeof(Point) * (*arraySizeInElements);
    Point * a = static_cast<Point *>(CoTaskMemAlloc(bytesToAlloc));
    *array = a;

    Point p1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    a[0] = p1;

    Point p2 = { 4, 5, 6 };
    a[1] = p2;

    Point p3 = { 7, 8, 9 };
    a[2] = p3;

    return 0;
}
```

The managed caller can then deal with the data very simply (in this example, I put all the interop code inside a static class called `NativeMethods`):

```
NativeMethods.Point[] points;
int size;
int result = NativeMethods.GetPoints(out points, out size);
if (result == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} points returned.", size);
    foreach (NativeMethods.Point point in points)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}, {2})", point.x, point.y, point.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work excellent. Did not know about the CoTAskMemAlloc. Thank you